# Java 2 ME javax.microedition.io -- where do I get this library from the internet

Tags: java, java-me

What exe do I need to install from the sun website for

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.microedition.io.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.location.*;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Sun Java Wireless Toolkit [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html). And if you are using netbeans means it's already included in the netbeans mobility pack. If you are using eclipse means you need to integrate with this toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Java Mobile Download overview page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/downloads/index.html).